Help needed in LDO design
I am trying to design a linear regulator. I started with a macro model for the error amplifier and added a pass stage. 50mA idc is the load. My desired output is 1.5V and Vin=1.8V. IBM180nm models. Vref or vinput to reg is 500mV and beta is 1/3.
There is something strange happening. As shown in the attached picture, my output is 1.503V. However high my loop gain would be, my output can't be more than 3*500mV i.e. it can't exceed 1.5V, it has to be less than 1.5V so that vout =  (A/1+A(beta)).Vref is obeyed. Can anyone suggest what might be ths issue?
When I model the pass gate with a vcvs, I get the expected output.


Make sure that the feedback network is correctly configured to provide the desired voltage regulation. Check the resistor values and connections to ensure they are providing the correct feedback.

I suggest going back to basics.  Remove the feedback controller you have, and prove that the rest of the circuit will work.  Assuming that all voltages in your circuit have to be within the range of the power supply (0 to 1.8V), then here is how I would approach that task:
Step 1:
Leaving the load at 0mA, find the voltage required at the gate terminal of the series pass transistor (let's call it M1) that gives the required output voltage (1.50V).  A DC sweep of your simulation should get the answer.
Step 2:
Next, increase the load current to be 50mA (set the load resistor to be 1.5V / 50mA = 30Ω), and find the new gate voltage that gives the required output voltage (1.50V).   Again, a DC sweep of your simulation should get the answer.
Step 3:
Check the results from Step 1 and Step 2 (the voltage at the gate of M1).  If these are beyond the voltage rails of the system (0V to 1.8V) then the MOSFET you have selected as the series pass element (M1) will never do the job, regardless of the "gain" of the feedback amplifier.
So, select a new series pass transistor that can meet the requirements.  Repeat steps 1 to 3 until all voltages are within the range of 0 to 1.8V.
Step 4:
Design the open-loop gain of your feedback amplifier.  At full load, some degree of voltage drop must occur in order to drive the error amplifier.  Let's assume the permitted voltage droop at full load is 1% of 1.5V, ie: 15mV.  In that case, the open-loop gain of your error amplifier must be at least:
(Voltage at Step 1) - (Voltage at Step 2) / 15mV.
Let's put some numbers in here to get a feel for what is required.  Assume that voltage at step 1 was found to be 1.2V (Vgsth of M1 = 0.3V), and at step 2 was 0.2V.  So the gain required will be:
(1.2V - 0.2V) / 15mV = 66.7.
This seems to be a reasonable open-loop gain for a small-signal error amplifier.  A higher gain will result in lower voltage droop at full load.
Hope this helps.
